# How to content size of UIScrollview in Autolayout

Tags: ios7

i want to add 5 views  of same size of simulator using UIScrollview. How could i can do? Specially content size of UIScrollview want to set which is approximately equals (320,2840) ?

Comment: What happened to your question? Did you find the answer?

Comment: You even bother to answer ??

Comment: Yes i got the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your requirement, you need the srollview to scroll vertically as (320,2840)(w,h). While doing this auto layout doesnt create any problem as once your scroll view is set, the 5 views inside id doesnt need to be set via autolayout.

1) First create a Scrollview and set its position on a view. create and IBOutelet for scrollView and then in our viewDidAppear sets its content size to 320,2840 like this

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 2840)];
```

and then create your UIViews in a for loop and add them inside your scrollview with a help a variable say "y" which sets your UIviews y co-ordinate everytime before adding it to your scrollview.

like this

```
int y = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        UIView *insideviews = [[UIView alloc]init];
        insideviews.frame = CGRectMake(0, y, 320, scr.frame.size.height);
        insideviews.tag = i;  // to distinguish them and use later

        [scr addSubview:insideviews];
        y = y + scr.frame.size.height;

    }
```

thats its, if you still have any problem tell me else you can accept the answer :) Good Luck